# How to get dimensions of an Image which is in Clipboard?

Tags: image, delphi, clipboard, dimensions

I want to know width and height of Image while it is in Clipboard, because if dimensions are too small then message like "Image is too small" should appear.

How to get width and height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are prepared to manually parse the various image formats that you want to support, you can have the VCL simply load the image for you (just make sure suitable `TGraphic` classes have been registered, such as `TGIFImage`, `TJPEGImage`, `TPNGImage`, etc), and then you can ask the image for its dimensions, eg:

```
uses
  Graphics, Clipbrd, Jpeg, PngImage, ...;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPicture;
begin
  p := TPicture.Create;
  try
    try
      p.Assign(Clipboard);
      // use p.Graphic, p.Graphic.Width, p.Graphic.Height as needed...
    except
      // unable to access Clipboard, or Clipboard
      // does not contain a supported image type
    end;
  finally
    p.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Or if supported, a `TWICImage`

Comment: @JerryDodge: Not in the style of the above code, no. Although `TWICImage` supports loading many image formats from files and streams, it only supports BMP images on the clipboard, because its `SaveToClipboardFormat()` and `LoadFromClipboardFormat()` methods delegate to an internal `Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap`, which only supports the `CF_BITMAP` clipboard format. Also, `TWICImage` is not registered with `TPicture.RegisterClipboardFormat()`, so `TPicture.Assign(TClipboard)` would not invoke `TWICImage` anyway.

Comment: @JerryDodge: If you want to use `TWICImage` to save/load formats other than BMP, you would likely have to use `TWICImage.SaveToStream()` and `TWICImage.LoadFromStream()` instead, and then read/write the clipboard data manually.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about bitmap I think you may try this.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var b:TBitmap;
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_BITMAP) then begin
    b:=TBitmap.Create;
    try
      b.Assign(Clipboard);
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(b.Width)+','+IntToStr(b.Height));
    finally
      b.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

you can instead of showmessage put If-statement and do what ever you want.

Comment: If you use `TPicture` instead, you can support other formats (JPG, PNG, etc).